# Hovering over an image does not seem to work properly

Tags: html, css

Some of my content is hidden and I would like it to show on hover. Point is I need it to work only on the image, not the whole text.
Below my html:

```css
.img-info {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

#info-1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#label-1:hover #info-1 {
  visibility: visible;
}

#info-2 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info-container-2:hover #info-2 {
  visibility: visible;
}

#info-3 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info-img-3:hover #info-3 {
  visibility: visible;
}

#info-4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info-img-4:hover #info-4 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <li>
    <input id="item-1" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-1" id="label-1">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-1" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-1">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-2" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-2">Text 2
          <span id="info-container-2" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-2">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-3" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-3">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-3" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-3">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-4" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-4">Text 1<span id="info-4">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
    <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info" />
  </li>
</form>
```

The code shows different approaches - the first one works but it refers to the whole label, the others should display hidden text when user hovers over just an image but they don't work and I would like to know why.

I've tried to keep it as minimal as possible.
I would be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no such thing as </input>

Comment: So if the first approach works... **what is the problem?**

Comment: Thank you. That is right. My bad. Unfortunately it does not solve the hover problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, but the case is I need the text to show on hovering over just an image. The first attempt involoves area taken by both the label text and the image. I need the other approaches to work (with just an image hovered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the text only appears when you hover the image.
You need to use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) to address the hidden text.

```css
.img-info {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

#info-1,
#info-2,
#info-3,
#info-4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info-container-1:hover+#info-1,
#info-container-2:hover+#info-2,
#info-container-3:hover+#info-3,
#info-container-4:hover+#info-4 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <li>
    <input id="item-1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item-1" id="label-1">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-1" class="info-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x15" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-1">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-2" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item-2">Text 2
          <span id="info-container-2" class="info-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x15" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-2">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-3" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item-3">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-3" class="info-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x15" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-3">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-4" type="checkbox">
    <label for="item-4">Text 1 <span id="info-container-4" class="info-container">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/15x15" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-4">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. Everything seems to work properly. But could you please explain the use of "+" sign and why is it neccesary?

Comment: @Gerard adding a class to the info spans seems better than fetching all their `ID`s.

Comment: @M.Nowakowski That's why I included the link in my answer. In short: your CSS is referring to child elements which cannot be found. My CSS is referring to siblings.

Comment: @ths You are probably right although we cannot know for certain if there is some Javascript that's referring to the IDs which is not included in the snippet. I'm always a bit hesitant to rewrite code completely.

Comment: But these `ID`s can still present so we DON'T affect the JS if there's some logic using them, and adding a class for all the spans will make it easier to read/write, for example the class will be "info-text": `.img-info + .info-text { ... }`

Comment: @ths Ah ok, you're right. I misunderstood you first remark.

Comment: Kindly, consider editing your answer, in the end the role of classes is that it gets rid of redundant code.

Comment: @Gerard Right, I missed that. Do not worry about reshaping my code. If there is a way to cut the code further like using the class instead of id then I would be very glad to see it and any good practices for that matter, like joining the css declarations into one (THANK YOU). :)

Answer (score 1):

Debugging tip, add some background color to the label would display the area taken up by the label tag, which in your case is the area taken up by the contents inside the label tag.

```
#info-1 {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

The code shall work, although you have to find some other approach, perhaps using JS.

Tip: with css property visibility: hidden, the element renders and takes up its space and is hidden, which in your case extends the width of the parent element *label*.

Try working with css property *display* instead

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The code works without js. I used sibling combinator as prompted in other answers. I was wondering about using the display instead of visibility. Know the difference more or less. May as well try it and see what suits my needs better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

this is your working code, you need to add (+) in the css, that is [adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), as you have not added the (+), browser consider it as the child of the hover element, and search for the `#info-n` within the hover element, this is also the reason that in the 1st `<li>` it worked out.

also 1st one is working on label and not on image its because you have added the css property to the `#label-1`.

```css
.img-info {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
}

#info-1,
#info-2,
#info-3,
#info-4 {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#info-container-1:hover+#info-1,
#info-container-2:hover+#info-2,
#info-container-3:hover+#info-3,
#info-container-4:hover+#info-4 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <li>
    <input id="item-1" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-1" id="label-1">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-1" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-1">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-2" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-2">Text 2
          <span id="info-container-2" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-2">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-3" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-3">Text 1 
          <span id="info-container-3" class="info-container">
          <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info"/></span> 
          <span id="info-3">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="item-4" type="checkbox"></input>
    <label for="item-4">Text 1
    <span id="info-container-4" class="info-container">
    <img src="info-tag.png" alt="information icon" class="img-info" /></span><span id="info-4">Text 1 Explication</span></label>
  </li>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. :) I think I understand know. So the selector without the sibling combinator treats the second element as a child instead of parallel one.